# Does SUSE SLES 12 SP5 supports Oracle OpenJDK 11?

Tags: java, opensuse, suse, openjdk-11, sles

I wanted to know does  SUSE SLES 12 SP5 supports oracle openjdk-11 or not?
As when i am trying to install and run it in SLES12 sp5  then i am getting the error

Error: dl failure on line 598
Error: failed Java/Sun-JRE/11.0.11/lib/server/libjvm.so, because /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by Java/Sun-JRE/11.0.11/lib/server/libjvm.so)

```
Means the current GLIBC version in my OS is 2.22 and oracle openjdk-11 requires a minimum of GLIBC version of 2.27 and higher.

So can anyone please let me know if SUSE SLES 12 SP5 supports oracle-openjdk-11 or not?
```

Comment: In what sense do you mean "support"?  Are you asking if oracle-openjdk-11 runs on SUSE?  Or are you asking if you can lodge SUSE support requests about it?   It is probably also relevant what version of SUSE you are running?

Comment: I also found this: https://software.opensuse.org/package/java-11-openjdk ... which is effectively saying the same thing.

Comment: But ... if you can't get the binarys that you downloaded to work, you could potentially download the OpenJDK Java 11u source tree and build it against the GLIBC version your OS provides.

Comment: @StephenC Can you let me know the steps of  how to build  it against the GLIBC version the required OS?

Comment: They should be in the standard OpenJDK build instructions.

Answer (score 0):

It stated clearly at the official SUSE website with L3 support [link](https://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/12-SP5/#allArch-development)

Unless your might be using any unofficial repositories which are not supported by SUSE